# Can't figure out how to address logic flaw in returning two values that sum to a target value in a Binary Tree

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, if-statement, binary-tree

I am solving the following question:

Given a Binary Search Tree and a target number, return true if there exist two elements in the BST such that their sum is equal to the given target.

Example 1:
Input:

```
    5
   / \
  3   6
 / \   \
2   4   7
```

Target = 9
Output: True

Example 2:
Input:

```
    5
   / \
  3   6
 / \   \
2   4   7
```

Target = 28
Output: False

I have written the following code:

```js
class TreeNode {
    constructor(val, left, right) {
        this.val = (val === undefined ? 0 : val)
        this.left = (left === undefined ? null : left)
        this.right = (right === undefined ? null : right)
    }
}

const findTarget = (root, k) => {
    const hash = {}
    const values = []
    // let val1, val2 //amended to =>
    let val1 = null
    let val2 = null

    const dfs = (c) => {
        if (!c) return
        values.push(c.val)
        hash[c.val] = c.val
        if (c.left) dfs(c.left)
        if (c.right) dfs(c.right)
    }
    dfs(root)
    for (let v of values) {
        // if (val1 && val2) return true //amended to =>
        if (val1 !== null && val2 !== null) return true
        if (hash[k - v] && !val1) val1 = v
        else if (hash[k - v] && val1) val2 = v
    }
    // return !!(val1 && val2) //amended to =>
    return (val1 !== null && val2 !== null)
}

// These are the test cases:
const tree = new TreeNode(5, new TreeNode(3, new TreeNode(2), new TreeNode(4)), new TreeNode(6, null, new TreeNode(7)))
const tree2 = new TreeNode(5, new TreeNode(3, new TreeNode(2), new TreeNode(4)), new TreeNode(6, null, new TreeNode(7)))
const tree3 = new TreeNode(2, new TreeNode(0, new TreeNode(-4), new TreeNode(1)), new TreeNode(3))
const tree4 = new TreeNode(0, new TreeNode(-2, null, new TreeNode(-1)), new TreeNode(3, null, new TreeNode(4)))

console.log(findTarget(tree, 9)) //true
console.log(findTarget(tree2, 28)) //false
console.log(findTarget(tree3, -1)) //true
console.log(findTarget(tree4, -2)) //true but I return false
```

However, the last one returns false but it should return true, I've stepped through it on a whiteboard it should work.  I suspect that 0 when assigned to either val1 or val2 is not passing the true/false test, but I don't know how to make it so that a value of 0 should return true.  At least that's what I believe to be the solution, but not sure on how to go about it rather than just adding another or statement that handles that condition.

Comment: `0` is falsey. So you're right, `(val1 && val2)` will evaluate to `false` if either is `0`.

Comment: You could instantiate `let val1 = null, val2 = null`, then check `val1 !== null && val2 !== null` instead.

Comment: Your suggestion makes perfect sense and I tried it, but it's still returning false.  I am not sure if I am missing anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `!val1` will be `true`, not only when `val1` is `null`, but also when it is 0. A similar thing happens with `&& val2` in the next `if`. And similarly you should compare `hash[k - v]` to `undefined`. So your code will be fixed when you replace that `if...else` block with:

```
        if (hash[k - v] !== undefined && val1 === null) val1 = v
        else if (hash[k - v] !== undefined && val1 !== null) val2 = v
```

Or, saving one check in the `else` part:

```
        if (hash[k - v] !== undefined) {
            if (val1 === null) val1 = v;
            else               val2 = v;
        }
```

I will here give another algorithm, which does not need to first collect all values in `hash`, but performs two in-order traversals, one left-to-right (i.e. non-descending values), and another right-to-left (i.e. non-ascending values). When the sum of the two found values is greater than the target, the traversal coming from the right should make a step. Otherwise the traversal coming from the left should make a step.

```js
class TreeNode {
    constructor(val, left=null, right=null) {
        this.val = val;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
    * inorder(first, last) {
        if (this[first]) yield * this[first].inorder(first, last);
        yield this;
        if (this[last]) yield * this[last].inorder(first, last);
    }
    find(k) {
        let asc = this.inorder("left", "right");
        let lo = asc.next();
        let desc = this.inorder("right", "left");
        let hi = desc.next();
        while (lo.value !== hi.value) { // while not the same node
             let sum = lo.value.val + hi.value.val;
             if (sum === k) return true;
             if (sum < k) lo = asc.next();
             else         hi = desc.next();
        }
        return false;
    }
}

const tree = new TreeNode(5, new TreeNode(3, new TreeNode(2), new TreeNode(4)), new TreeNode(6, null, new TreeNode(7)))
const tree2 = new TreeNode(5, new TreeNode(3, new TreeNode(2), new TreeNode(4)), new TreeNode(6, null, new TreeNode(7)));
const tree3 = new TreeNode(2, new TreeNode(0, new TreeNode(-4), new TreeNode(1)), new TreeNode(3));
const tree4 = new TreeNode(0, new TreeNode(-2, null, new TreeNode(-1)), new TreeNode(3, null, new TreeNode(4)));
console.log(tree.find(9))   // true
console.log(tree2.find(28)) // false
console.log(tree3.find(-1)) // true
console.log(tree4.find(-2)) // true
```

Comment: I've tried the first part of your solution.  However, one new and last test case fails. `const tree5 = new TreeNode(0, new TreeNode(-3, new TreeNode(-4)), new TreeNode(2, new TreeNode(1)))` The return of `console.log(findTarget(tree5, 1)) //true` but I return false.  Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: I get true. Did you do the change correctly? Did you by accident delete the first `if` in the loop? See it produce `true` on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5ymfdc6/)

Comment: ahh my mistake, in the else if I still had `hash[k - v] !== undefined && val1` rather than `hash[k - v] !== undefined && val1 !== null`.  I would assume the first one doesn't work because if val1 is assigned 0, then val2 never gets assigned because the condition is never met.

Comment: Indeed. like you say.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop when searching for the corresponding hash value looks a bit suspect, particularly the use of the not operator as robinsax has observed.  Suggest simplifying to something along the lines of...

```js
class TreeNode {
    constructor(val, left, right) {
        this.val = (val === undefined ? 0 : val);
        this.left = (left === undefined ? null : left);
        this.right = (right === undefined ? null : right);
    }
}

const findTarget = (root, k) => {
    const hash = new Map();

    const dfs = (c) => {
        if (!c) return;
        hash.set( c.val, ( hash.get( c.val ) || 0 ) + 1 );
        if (c.left) dfs(c.left);
        if (c.right) dfs(c.right);
    }
    dfs(root);
    
    for ( let v in  [...hash.keys()] ) {
      // Check to see if entry k-v exists.  Also, if v is the same as k-v then
      // ensure that there is more than one v.
      if ( hash.get( k - v ) && ( v == k - v ? 1 < hash.get( v ) : true ) ) {
        return true;
      }
    };

    return false;
}

const tree = new TreeNode(5, new TreeNode(3, new TreeNode(2), new TreeNode(4)), new TreeNode(6, null, new TreeNode(7)));
const tree2 = new TreeNode(5, new TreeNode(3, new TreeNode(2), new TreeNode(4)), new TreeNode(6, null, new TreeNode(7)));
const tree3 = new TreeNode(2, new TreeNode(0, new TreeNode(-4), new TreeNode(1)), new TreeNode(3));
const tree4 = new TreeNode(0, new TreeNode(-2, null, new TreeNode(-1)), new TreeNode(3, null, new TreeNode(4)));
const tree5 = new TreeNode(1);
const tree6 = new TreeNode(1, new TreeNode(1), new TreeNode(2));

console.log(findTarget(tree, 9)); //true
console.log(findTarget(tree2, 28)); //false
console.log(findTarget(tree3, -1)); //true
console.log(findTarget(tree4, -2)); //true
console.log(findTarget(tree5, 2)); // false because 1 appears once
console.log(findTarget(tree6, 2)); // true because 1 appears twice
```

**EDIT** Added logic to accommodate duplicate nodes, along with test cases tree5 and tree6.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I've never used the hasOwnProperty before, and looking at the documentation,  I am still a bit confused.  Is it the same as searching for `k- v` in `Object.keys(hash)`?

Comment: @Altaf yes, the line `hash[c.val] = c.val` is effectively adding a new attribute ( or property ) to the `hash` object, and the `hasOwnProperty( k - v )` function is simply looking to see if the corresponding property exists.  Eg, if `hash[ '2' ]` is the current value being checked and `k = 9`, then `hasOwnProperty( 7 )` simply checks to see if `hash[ 7 ]` exists.

Comment: tried this solution as well, however, the test case where `const tree5 = new TreeNode(1)` should return false when `console.log(findTarget(tree5, 2)) //false`, but I return true

Comment: @Altaf great test case that points out a flaw in my proposed algorithm!  Am editing with a fix.